# How to limit coin cell battery voltage to 2.0V and below?

Tags: voltage-regulator

The backup battery voltage for my device is specified to have a maximum voltage of 2.0V, whilst coin cells are normally around 3.0V.

How would I be able to limit the voltage to 2.0V, but in a way that does not draw much quiescent current to deplete the coin cell?

At such low currents (backup battery voltage rail current is specified with a 150nA limit),

[TPS78230](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps78230.pdf) linear regulator has a quiescent current of 500nA which appears to be good! I wonder if there are any lower quiescent current solutions?

Comment: Lithium coin cell batteries are 3.0V.  I wonder if the designers of your device had a different battery chemistry in mind.  Could you post a datasheet for the device?

Comment: Why not use an alkaline, silver-oxide, or zinc-air coin cell? They're all around 1.5V.

Comment: peak load is 150nA. Duration unspecified.